# Create copy of file and change its name

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

As the title states I want to make a copy of a file in my Google Drive with a specific name, and then change the name of the copy. While I was able to make the copy, I can't seem to change its name.

The idea is roughly:

1. Copy file with specific name "HelloWorld.xls"
2. Change the name of the copy to a user input, e.g. "HelloWorldSomething.xls"

The code which I use to copy is like this, but here I need to hardcode the FileID - I would rather use the filename.

```
public String copySheetFromDrive() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    File newSheet = new File();
    Drive.Files.Copy copyFile = driveService.files().copy("idofthefile", newSheet);
    updateProperty(copyFile.getFileId());
    System.out.println("File ID: " + copyFile.getFileId());
    return copyFile.getFileId();
}
```

as far as I could find, I need to work with `FileList`s and filter these, but the Drive documentation is not very clear about how to do that, so if anyone has an idea how to solve this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to set the name of the new file before copying it.

```
File newSheet = new File();
newSheet.setName("someName");
```